# Compare the last 24h with the same period a year ago in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to compare the last 24h with the same period a year ago.

If I do:

```
event_date < now() - INTERVAL 365 DAY and event_date > now() - INTERVAL 366 DAY
```

it does not take into consideration leap years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause you would need to create the condition for the records a year ago would be:

```
WHERE event_date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
AND  event_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

By doing it this way you will not have to worry about the leap years.

To get the data for the current past 24 hours you would use:

```
WHERE event_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
AND  event_date <= NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    event_date < now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
AND event_date > now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

or try

```
event_date BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
               AND (now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```